# Find text and replace all matching using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have

```
var removeNotification = " (F)";
listVariable = listVariable.replace(removeNotification, '');
```

This works partially, but it only finds the first " (F)" within the string and replaces it to "". There are about many others I need to change as well.

What I need is a way to find ALL matches and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var removeNotification = /\s\(\F\)/g;   // "g" means "global"
listVariable = listVariable.replace(removeNotification, '');
console.log(listVariable)
```

This will replace ALL matches, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way if `removeNotification` cannot be hard coded:

```
// escape regular expression special characters
var escaped = removeNotification.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')

// remove all matches
listVariable = listVariable.replace(new RegExp(escaped, 'g'), '');
```